# Magento adminhtml observer looking in mage

Tags: php, magento

Im trying to use an observer in the admin section, ive used the same format successfully in the frontend so im sure its going to be something simple here but when i insert :

```html
    <adminhtml>

        <events>

            <adminhtml_catalog_product_attribute_edit_prepare_form>
                <observers>
                  <fisheye_featuredattributes>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>featuredattributes/observer</class>
                    <method>featured_attributes</method>
                  </fisheye_featuredattributes>
                </observers>
            </adminhtml_catalog_product_attribute_edit_prepare_form>

        </events>

    </adminhtml>
```

into config.xml I get :

> Warning: include(Mage/Featuredattributes/Model/Observer.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory  in /var/www/html/magentocom/public_html/lib/Varien/Autoload.php on line 94

Like i said the code works fine for a front end observer its when i place it ito the adminhtml tags it fails? Dont understand why its looking in mage for the class?

Thanks in advance
Dave

Comment: can you share your full config.xml ?

Comment: try something like, ABC_Featuredattributes_Model_Observer where class mentioned

Answer (score 0):

I guess the reason is the scope of your observer model, if it works on frontend.

If your model is in `<frontend>` node, then it is not going to be accessible by this event. If your model is in `<adminhtml>` or `<global>` then there is an error somewhere else and having a look at your whole config.xml would help.

For further reference:
If anything (model, helper, block, ...) is under

- `<frontend>` it would be accessible only from frontend
- `<adminhtml>` it would be accessible only from backend (admin)
- `<global>` it would be accessible for both front- and backend

Answer (score 0):

I turned out to be as simple as i had not defined a model in my config xml.
Thank you to all who posted and helped me with this issue.
Dave